# Excluded Crawled - currently not indexed

Tags: search, indexing, console

I have been going through this issue from last past of days. Some of the site's pages are not indexing in Google.

For instance, I have been working on this site https://tradefills.com and most of the pages are excluded from the indexing. I have checked each page and could not find any issue.

I have some other sites as well and facing the same issue in other one as well.

[image]

Comment: I am very interested to learn more about this too. I am assuming that Google just doesn't see some pages as important as others? Same with images. It doesn't seem to want them all indexed. But by what measure?

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem i've submit the url almost 1 month ago but still not indexed. i found the docs said

```
and we cannot predict or guarantee when these URLs will be displayed.
```